# VBA code to find a color in a selection and change it

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write a code that will find red cells and change them to green within a selection. I am a total beginner so this will look barbaric but here it is. I can get it to go down a column and change the colors along the way but what I am really looking to do is have it do that within a selection and when it gets to the bottom of the selected column go back up to the next column within the selection and so on until there is no data available. Here is what I have. Thanks a bunch for any help!

```
Sub change_colour()



Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

Do While Selection.Interior.Color = 255
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for providing your code. Could you clarify: what is your code *currently* doing, what would you like it to do instead, and what (if anything) have you tried to get it to work?

Comment: I got a solution below, is there a way to mark the post resolved?

Comment: Yup! Click the check mark next to an answer to mark it as the accepted answer - it will turn green to indicate it is accepted

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is set a `Range` variable to the current selection, and just loop through that range and check the color. If it is red, change it.

You're close, but there's some unnecessary code here (which is to be expected as you're learning).

I think the key is declaring and assigning the `Range` variable and the use of a `For..Each` loop.

```
Public Sub Change_Colour()

    Dim rSel As Range, c As Range

    Set rSel = Selection

    For Each c In rSel

        If c.Interior.Color = 255 Then

            c.Interior.Color = 5296274

        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

So this code declares two range variables `rSel` and `c`. `rSel` is initiated as the user's selection. I use the `For..Each` loop with the range variable `c` to loop through all of the cells in the selection.

The `If` statement is a stripped-down version of what you have, checking to see if the cell's color is red and changing it to green if so.

Comment: No problem! `For..Each` is a great tool that I use often.